# What does last major release of Windows mean?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

Check out this link:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9

And an excerpt from above link:

> ### **What happened to Windows 9?**
>
> There was never a Windows 9, Microsoft skipped this number and went to
>   10 instead. Company officials decided to choose 10 because they
>   believe this release is a 'Perfect 10' ***and to also signify this is the
>   last major release of Windows.***

What does it mean by 'last major release of Windows'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the page, I came to the answer:

> ### Are you saying there will be no more versions of Windows after Windows 10?
>
> Microsoft is moving Windows to a servicing model with Windows 10. The
>   days of major revisions or what are called big bang releases are no
>   more. As Microsoft Program Manager for Windows Terry Myerson described
>   it:
>
> This is more than a one-time upgrade: once a Windows device is
>   upgraded to Windows 10, we will continue to keep it current for the
>   supported lifetime of the device – at no additional charge. With
>   Windows 10, the experience will evolve and get even better over time.
>   We’ll deliver new features when they’re ready, not waiting for the
>   next major release. We think of Windows as a Service – in fact, one
>   could reasonably think of Windows in the next couple of years as one
>   of the largest Internet services on the planet.
>
> And just like any Internet service, the idea of asking "What version
>   are you on?" will cease to make sense – which is great news for our
>   Windows developers.
>
> Source:
>   http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/01/21/the-next-generation-of-windows-windows-10/

Pretty interesting.

Comment: Indeed. Both exciting and a little scary! However, taking from experience with Office 365 I'd take this with a pinch of salt. I've no doubt this is the current intent but whether it survives more than a few years - who knows? It is certainly a very welcome development. Expect to see licensing changing shortly as well. ;)

Comment: @JulianKnight: I agree with you completely. Gotta wait and see whether this stands the test of time.

Comment: "keep it current for the supported lifetime of the device", sounds like apple to me, when they get tired of supporting 3-5 year old hardware you have to buy another PC to keep a current version of W10. Microsoft will determine just how "old" your hardware is. Doesn't excite me at all.